# To prove completeness in finer topology?

Tags: general-topology, cauchy-sequences, complete-spaces

I encountered an argument which goes like this,

We want to prove topological space ($X,O_1$) is complete(every cauchy sequence converges).
Let ($X,O_2$) be topology which is finer(strong) than ($X,O_1$).

**To prove ($X,O_1$) is complete, it suffices to prove the completeness of ($X,O_2$).**

But I'm confused. If I could prove in coaser(Wearker) topology, completeness follows in more fine topology, and **I can say nothing if I work in finer topology**,I believe.

Is this kind of argument wrong ? Or am I missing something?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Completeness is in general only a property of metric spaces, not in general of topological spaces. Not sure your question makes sense.

Comment: As MateInTwo already commented, the question does not make sense as stated. Perhaps one could ask this question, if two metrics $d_1, d_2$ are given such that their induced topologies are in such a relation. But this is false, as there exists non-complete metrics on the reals, which induce the usual topology.

Comment: The only related theorem, which I could think of, is that if two metrics (or their uniformities) are comparable, but induce the *same* topolgy, then completeness of the *coarser* one implies completeness of the *finer* one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By definition, a sequence $\{a_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ converges to a point $b$ if for every open set $U$ there is $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that the set $\{a_n:n\geq k\}$ is contained in $U$. So, since in a coarser topology there are fewer open sets to check, whenever a sequence is convergent in a topology $(X,\mathcal{O}_2)$ it would also be convergent in a weaker topology $(X,\mathcal{O}_1)$.

Also, since the definition of completeness (for metric spaces) is that every Cauchy sequence converges, then proving that a finer metric space $(X,d_2)$ is complete suffices to show that a coarser metric space $(X,d_1)$ (same set) is complete.

Comment: For your argumentation you would need that a Cauchy-sequence for $d_2$ is Cauchy-sequence with respect for $d_1$, which is not the case at all. See also my above comment.